# How to process messages in the same order from queue using multiple servers in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jms, activemq-classic

We have a ActiveMQ queue which will receive 100k stock order messages(each message contains stock name, sell price, bid price in json format) per second. 
Out of 100k messages/sec there can be n no.of messages of single stock. If we receive multiple messages of same stock then we need to process all those messages in the same order using java. 
We can't process 100k messages/second using single listener in one server.
Need to process it by using multiple listeners & servers but display the result in UI using the same order that is placed in Queue.

Read Stock Queue--> Validate the request -->Update the Stock price in UI

Example message:-
{
   stockName:"TCS",
   sellPrice:"102",
   bidPrice:"100"
}

Can you suggest solution for the above problem.

Comment: The entire purpose of multi-threading is to enable _concurrency_ (i.e., the ability to do things in no particular order.) So, if you want certain things to be done in a certain order, the best way is to make sure they are all done in the same thread.  @SharonBenAsher's answer is the key: Have one queue for each "listener", and use hashing to ensure that all transactions involving the same stock are sent to the same queue.

Comment: Yes Solomon Slow, but the requirement is to process the message in the same order. User1 placed TCS bid for 101, user2 placed TCS stock bid for 102. Then in UI we should see 102 for TCS. Also we will receive 10k message/sec per stock at some times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposal:
You need to split the queue to sub queues based on the stock name. you can split based on the first letter(s) of the stock name. this will give you ample parallel capabilities while ensuring that all messages of the same stock land on one queue.
there will need to be one reader from the main queue but all it does is forwarding the messages to the sub queues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. 
This will require 26 queues(A to Z). FYI we have around 4k stocks. Also we need to add those many listeners/instances though few stocks will have very high volume(end up in high utilisation of those listeners) and few stocks will have less no.of messages. We might end up in less utilisation of those listeners.

For example, if we get 10k messages/sec with respect to queue starting with letter A then that may not be possible to process all those messages using single listener with in 1 second.

Comment: Also we are adding one more reader to read from main queue and forward it to sub queue. ( read the message, check the stock name, forward to another queue) This will add extra processing time. Also this should be done using single listener to maintain the order. As we are handling 100k messages/sec this would be difficult to process all those messages with single listener.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use non-persistent publication to topics instead of queues. Topics give you the flexibility of

1. choosing subscription wildcards and
2. possibly adding other services later to this architecture. You might not require this now, but maybe in 5 years you will need another GUI or some form of monitoring or replay service. In case you used topics you can just plugin new subscribers - you don't have to change your publication side for those...

You can use durable subscriptions if you need more persistence.

Message order is guaranteed within the same publication topic so you should make the stock name part of the topic. You could publish on something like ORDER.STOCK.TCS.

But having a balanced load based on stock names is tricky because some letters like Z are very rare, while others are frequent. So in addition to the stock name add the stock name's hash%100 to the topic. For Example if the hashcode of TCS is 12357 and you do modulo 100, you publish this on ORDER.STOCK.TCS.57

Let's say you have 10 subscriber's, each subscriber could then make 10 subscriptions. For example subscriber 1 would subscribe to ORDER.STOCK.*.0, ORDER.STOCK.*.1, ... ORDER.STOCK.*.9

Subscriber 2 would subscribe to ORDER.STOCK.*.10, ORDER.STOCK.*.11, ... ORDER.STOCK.*.19

If you have 5 subscribers, each one does 20 subscriptions (you get the idea).
The reason for this is that

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Above approach will create 400k topics when we have 4k stocks. 
When we use stock name hash%100 how to ensure the order of messages.
Also there should be only listener each topic otherwise each listener will get same message(since it is topic).

Comment: No - for one stock, like MSFT you would publish on only ONE topic: ORDER.STOCK.MSFT.31, for example. That will be 4k topics for 4k stocks. The trick is that you have approximately 4000/100 = 40 stocks ending in ‘31’ so a subscriber listening on *.*.*.31 will get those 40 stocks. All messages in original order.

Comment: All the stocks of MSFT will go to ORDER.STOCK.MSFT.31 correct. As it is topic can we add multiple listeners /subscribers to increase the processing speed. If yes how to ensure the order. At the end we need to display the same incoming order in ui.

Comment: Don't add multiple listeners per topic. Just one. And for that one the order is ensured. But you can also use queues if you like: The first order idea is to use the first letter as part of the queue name: STOCK.M, STOCK.N, .. - and your first queue consumer would get messages from queues A-G, for example. Your second consumer from queue H-M. BUT how to distribute you load evenly ? Some letters have much more traffic than others.. so the better variation of this is to use the hash of the stock name as part of the queue name. first consumer processes STOCK.0-10 for example.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement and we used an open source framework called LMAX Disruptor, supposedly highly performant concurrency framework. You can experiment around it, https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Getting-Started.

On a very high level:

1. Put the Stocks received into a ringbuffer [core data structure that 
   the framework is built upon], this would be the consumer for
   ActiveMQ and producer for the ringbuffer.
2. The consumers/workers[in your case multiple - mulltiple here is a
   worker-thread for each unique stock-name] pick up the Stocks from
   ringbuffer in ordered fashion. In the worker/listener, you can
   handle event based on condition.

I've just committed sample code trying to demonstrate your use case, for your reference:
https://github.com/reddy73/Disruptor-Example

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, I have checked it. How to scale it using multiple servers. Will it work when we use more than 1 server.

Comment: When I use 4 workers & 4 ringBufferSize, order is missing(2,4,8 & 6 instead of 2,4,6 & 8). Is it always 2 workers & 2 ringBufferSize ?

Worker[2] consumed [1] Stock where Stock[id: 2, StockName: TCS.
Worker[3] consumed [1] Stock where Stock[id: 4, StockName: TCS.
Worker[2] consumed [2] Stock where Stock[id: 8, StockName: TCS.
Worker[1] consumed [1] Stock where Stock[id: 6, StockName: TCS.